# Save an entity to memcache but not the disk with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, objectify

I've got an entity that I use for non-critical logging of game completion rates, basically just simple counters. Due to the fact this will be updated hundreds of thousands of times a day (and hopefully growing) it'll live (almost) permanently in memcache.

To save myself from having to pay for those hundreds of thousands of writes of non-critical data I'm happy to risk having to object persisted in memcache with a disk write only every 15 minutes or so.

I can't see any obvious way to do it, but I was wondering if there was something like `ofy().save().entity()` that could be used to write to the cache but not the disk? If not, is there any other easy way to write an entity to memcache?

If I need to handle this myself, is there a way I can use the memcache keys that Objectify uses to read the object stored by objectify, or am I better off just handling all the caching myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this with Objectify alone. However, you can fake it pretty effectively.

Objectify caches entities in the namespace `ObjectifyFactory.MEMCACHE_NAMESPACE`. All cache keys are the stringified Key object (`Key<?>.toWebSafeString()`). All cache values are gae low-level api `Entity` objects.

You can manually convert back and forth between Entity and POJO with `ofy().load().fromEntity(entity)` and `ofy().save().toEntity(pojo)`.

That's probably enough to accomplish what you want. Note that Objectify's builtin cache behavior is to clear the entry on write (save/delete) and only to fill the cache on get. Also note that there is a special sentinel value `NEGATIVE` (the literal string) which indicates the cached fact that the entity does not exist.

Comment: but why make it go through objectify if he can just use the memcached api directly?

Comment: This is a question you should ask the OP, not me. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: but how does this help any more than using simply memcached? you should explain if there is any advantage of this cumbersome way compared with memcache to make it a better quality answer. I see no point of using this over somply memcache alone.

Comment: There are a lot of advantages to using Objectify to transmogrify POJOs into `Entity` objects. `Entity`s are serializable and serialize into a canonical representation that can be migrated with Objectify's annotations. As for overlapping with the `MEMCACHE_NAMESPACE` - I don't know. You might get a less speculative answer (from the OP) if you ask in the comment area for the question, not in this answer.