# Read an entity(saved by Objectify) from memcache only, not from the disk

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to read an entity from Memcache only. I understand that there are high chances of it getting evicted, but it's not that important for this scenario, and it's present in Memcache even after executing this code.

This entity is saved with Objectify. I can see it in Memcache from Appengine Console, when searched with namespace=ObjectifyCache, key=URL-safe-key, key-type=Java-String.

When I try to get it using native method, it returns null.

```
MemcacheService cache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService(ObjectifyFactory.MEMCACHE_NAMESPACE);
cache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));

Object object = cache.get(KeyFactory.createKeyString("key", "name"));
if(object == null) {
    log(Level.WARNING, "null returned from memcache, " + KeyFactory.createKeyString("key", "name"));
    return;
}

MyPojo pojo = ofy().load().fromEntity((Entity) object);
```

I have [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122295/3968247) few questions here but it didn't help though it seems pretty straight. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing obvious thing indeed. As @stickfigure pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122295/3968247), `save()` and `delete()` through Objectify is clearing the entry from cache, and `load()` is filling it again. I was trying to `get()` it immediately after saving it.

I can use `MemcacheService.Contains()` method to see if it was recently saved and then can load normally.

This may not give expected result always as entries can be removed anytime from cache, but in my case it will save millions of read operations where chances of `Entity` present in datastore is less than 1%. And even if I miss it through eviction it won't impact much.